# Android - Correct way to override onDestroy()?

Tags: android, android-activity, android-lifecycle

I see examples of both, so which is the best way to override `onDestroy()` in an Activity...

```
@Override
protected void onDestroy() {

    super.onDestroy();

    /*
     *  Clean up and stop listeners etc. AFTER calling super.
     */
    myLeakyObject = null;
}
```

...or...

```
@Override
protected void onDestroy() {

    /*
     *  Clean up and stop listeners etc. BEFORE calling super.
     */
    myLeakyObject = null;

    super.onDestroy();

}
```

...or doesn't it matter?

Comment: Yes, thanks. From looking at the comments and answers on that page, they all seem to concur that you should (or may as well) always declare `super.onDestroy()` it at the end - i.e., as in my second example.